# show that the process is a martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

maybe you will have an idea how to show that : the process $(exp(X_t-\frac{1}{2}Y_t))$ is a martingale? Where $h \in L^2([0,T])$, $T< \infty$, $X_t=\int_0^th(s)dW_s$ and $Y_t=\int_0^th^2(s)ds$ for $t \le T$

Comment: Yes: use Itô's formula. Surely you already tried, so which obstacle did you meet while doing so?

Comment: I haven't had Ito formula yet

Comment: Ha. And the words "exponential martingale" do not ring any bell either? Then what exactly do you know which could prove useful to show this?

Comment: *"for $t \le"*... what?

Answer (score 1):

If "exponential martingale" does not ring a bell that you may want to try the following approach. 
Note that your process $S_t := \exp(X_t - \frac{1}{2}Y_t)$ is a Geometric Brownian motion with a non-constant volatility parameter $h(t)$, that is, is satisfies the following SDE
$$\mathrm{d} S_t = S_t h(t)\mathrm{d}W_t $$
which reads 
$$ S_t = 1+ \int_0^t S_s h(s) \mathrm{d}W_s.$$
You can use Ito's lemma to show it. Then for $\int_0^t S_s h(s) \mathrm{d}W_s$ apply the following

**Theorem.**
The stochastic integral $\int_0^t Z_s(\omega) \mathrm{d}W_s(\omega) $ is a martingale for any $Z_t(\omega) \in L^2([0,T])$.

The proof of this theorem can be found in most textbooks, and possibly it was provided in your lecture. Let me know if you cannot find it.

You can also have a look [here](http://www.randomservices.org/random/brown/Geometric.html) (point 13.), there is a direct proof of a special case when $h$ is constant, that is, $h(t) = \sigma$.

Comment: I find your solution  very difficult, I've never had SDE.
Exponential martingale is known to me ( for $\lambda >0$ $Z_t=exp(\lambda W_t-\lambda^2t/2)$ is a martingale), so maybe you will help me to solve this task using exponential martingale.

Comment: You don't need to think about SDEs here, apply Ito's lemma to your $(S_t)$, can you do that? Your question has been kept on hold, so try to edit it, for example you could add your attempts (application of Ito's lemma to $(S_t)$).